# Does slaying or capturing monsters offer better chances at tempered investigations?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

While hunting tempered monsters, I try to pick up as many tracks and break as many parts of the monster as I can, in order to increase my chances of receiving another tempered investigation. Since not picking up tracks or not breaking monster parts doesn't give a chance at tempered investigations, the choice here is obvious.

It is also possible to receive an investigation when either slaying or capturing a monster. Does either of those methods offer better chances?